# TXS0108E8 Specification in Mbps, what is the equivalent in MHz?

Tags: microcontroller, microchip, level-shifting

I am looking at a datasheet of a level converter (https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0108e.pdf?ts=1634046719564&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTXS0108E - TXS0108E8) and it says it has

Maximum data rates
– 110 Mbps (push pull)
– 1.2 Mbps (open drain)

Does 1 bit corresponds to 1 clk cycle and then 1bps = 1 Hz in this case?

Another question is about the push pull. I am not sure I understand. Do I need to have an inverter at the outputs? I need to work at 20 MHz, meaning the voltage from 3.3V to 5V and vice-versa will change at this frequency. The input of my circuit is a clk signal that will be delayed by the delay lines.

[image]

Comment: 1m cable is  @ 50 Ohms?  and 5 ns delay?  Why do you have 250 ps delay lines.   $$ $$ What is your signal integrity spec? expectations?  Your choices don't make sense yet  https://tinyurl.com/ygv78f8t  Notice I added parastic C, ESL and trace E looks much better than my simulation of yours.

Comment: It seems you will have computational delays and many other delays ? What are you trying to accomplish doing this?  This is NOT how to generate quadrature signals NOR phase lock 2 clocks.  Say what you are trying to do at a higher  level rather than this.

Comment: Is this a BER test set? a QPSK simulator , a phase margin analyzer, a coherent QPSK demodulator  or what?   too many assumptions will cause unintended failures...

Comment: TY for info. What is the pulse rate of Laser?  slow? fast?  Does  MCU clock stability matter?   or just delay time from Shot_W rising edge to leading edge of Laser pulse.   What is **range** of delay error to be corrected from 820 ns? and preferred error **tolerance**?    +/- x? ?

Comment: If the pulse delay error is  < 5ns=1/20MHz   Why not have a circuit that detects and nulls this error with an analog servo-electronics?   e.g. high speed diode and phase delay loop.  Also I think this level shifter is not needed.  The DS1023 may work with 3.3V input on Vdd=5V +/-0.1

Comment: Indeed, the DS1023 detects 3.3V in the input, however the output is still 5V and I can't input 5V in the `CLK in` of the MCU, since this pin isn't 5V tolerant. Pulse rate of laser is one pulse per clk cycle as mentioned in the figure. I need to illuminate around 820 and check the timing window I have the expected result (eg. from 819 ns to 825 ns). I will perform some statistical analysis, that is why I can't have only one laser pulse at the specific clk edge of 820ns, I need to begin like T0+820-25ns to T0+820+25ns.

Comment: 5v to 3.3V can be done with passive ratios. Is one pulse cycle 1us = 1 MHz  I was thinking of have pulse window error detector actually control the delay locally. But I guess not possible.  74ALV, ARM's are fast but CML or ECL is faster on risetime.

Comment: The Shot_W is generated by the MCU, so it takes several clk cycles and I can't delay it using NOPS for instance or other type of intrinsic delay from the MCU, the only solution I found was to delay the clk and so the whole Shot_W window with it. The idea works fine, I tested with an FPGA, but the FPGA was only capable to introduce 50ps*256 (8 bits) delays, which is not enough for me. So my real problem now is that I want to be sure that this logic level converter will be capable to transfer 5V into 3.3V for a 20 MHz signal.

Comment: I would have thought the 100 ps laser was more like 150 kHz.  There are other ways to create 820ns delays in hardware

Comment: No, it is 20 MHZ and it shots 100 ps each clock cycle. With Shot_W I can choose from the laser source if I want all shots inside that window or only one after Shot_W is up, so it will select only one pulse, which is my case.

Comment: Could you give some ideas on other ways to create delay?

Comment: for 820 ns delay of  20 MHz clock or 50 ns cycle is a 4 bit synchronous counter delay of 16 counts x 50ns=800ns + 20ns  prop delay  ??  Do you really want to pulse laser up to 20 MHz rate with 820 ns delay? or just one -shot

Comment: for 820 ns delay of  20 MHz clock or 50 ns cycle is a 4 bit synchronous counter delay of 16 counts x 50ns=800ns + 20ns  prop delay  ??  Do you really want to pulse laser up to 20 MHz rate with 820 ns delay? or just one -shot in a 1us window

Comment: One shot at ~795 ns, another at 795.25 ns, another at 795.50 ns up to 855ns for example, I need to sweep around 820 ns, could be more or less. So one shot each 250 ps delay increment.

Comment: I found another logic level shifter that behaves as a buffer that should work fine up to 50 MHz for my 5V0 to 3V3 clk signal (SN74LV1T126DBVR). Do you happen to know it @Tony?

Comment: No, but the prop delay is large and not stable.   If you want stable delay,that is fast use CML type logic.(current mode) rather than voltage mode.

Comment: I still have no idea where you detect the laser pulse and it's position or phase error or the reason you are sweeping it.  Spectroscopy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's 2 bits per Hz, that is, the double-data-rate throughput. So a device specified as 110Mbps will have a bandwidth of about 55MHz. So this device should be adequate for your 20MHz single-data-rate application, but mind the inserted turn-around delay.

'Push-pull' operation only means that the driving device drives both high and low. This is typical of most GPIOs. This is differentiated from an 'open collector' or 'open drain' driver that only drives low and requires a pull-up to make logic high (I2C bus for example.)

Comment: So If I understand correctly, in my case is push pull since my input is a clk source right? I am confused because open drain would fix the value at vdd or gnd, so I don't understand why there is a bit rate for open drain if the voltage is fixed by the pull up or down resistor.

Comment: Yes, your clock source is push-pull and needs no pullup. Open drain requires a pull-up. For this translator, it needs to be on the driver side, as the translator needs to see the signal make a 0-1 transition to activate the active pull-up on the higher-voltage side. This transition will be slower than push-pull, so the achievable bit rate will be slower.

Answer (score 3):

For NRZ data is takes 2bits 01...01 to make 1Hz so 2MBps = 1MHz

The ratio of pulse width is 30:1 is also the ratio of On R to OFF R pullup means push-pull with low R in each swing is what you need for > 1 MHz.

To optimize this, the traces , cable ,should be matched to minimize reflections if the path length is > 10% of a wavelength at 2e8 m/s for a dielectric constant of 4 for epoxy and plastic insulated cables. If not terminated then there is overshoot for that path length but matched at source so minimal reflect at source. But terminations of 4k dampens the ringing somewhat without drawing too much power. These are tradeoffs.

These use high input impedance so ringing does occur but as long as that decays before the trailing clock edge resamples the data, integrity is preserved. So improve integrity in other systems, (Canbus, RS485 etc) a matched load, is used  but then more power is dissipated and the  Voltage is reduced 50% but without (as much) overshoot. Here the comparator or inverter threshold should be 50% of the final 4k loaded or initial voltage, which from 400 Ohms is only 11% drop in voltage.

So the level conversion must consider these factors of path length and output and load capacitance with the driver Rs to optimize signal integrity.  When there is no skew between clock and data and no matched load , overshoot and ringing decay occurs from the ESL equivalent path inductance and parasitic or line capacitance such that \$Z_0=\sqrt{L/C}\$ for the desired link.  This ought to be chosen to match the source RdsOn which is not given and that reduced with higher output Vdd. For 5V CMOS drivers this can often vary from 66 Ohms for low Vdd to ~ 12 Ohms for max Vdd and sometimes series R is added in these cases to match the cable or trace impedance to reduce the reflections at source for long echo times. But this IC has higher Ron values **" (on the order of 300 Ω to 500 Ω) "** (You might be able to correlate this R from rise/fall times from C given.) so this is designed for traces and cables in this range of impedance.

A complete spec of path length and impedance ought to be determined if you wish to optimize signal integrity and immunity from stray noise in your design to choose the best match at source.  This can be simulated if you need more explanation after you detail your objectives for level conversion with ambient noise and path length.

Simulation with modifications . Better results do not use this IC.  Trace E
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I have an instrument that will provide a 20 MHz clk, my microcontroller will use the clk of this instrument since I need both to be in phase. I will use the dealy line to change the phase between the instrument providing the clk and the microcontroller. I will use a 1 m cable from the instrument to the delay lines and another 1 m cable from the delay line to the microcontroller. I will try to better understand your answer, since it is too complex for my current knowledge, so I need to read about the terms you mentioned here. Thanks again.

Comment: This is not a perfect model https://tinyurl.com/ygedgth9  But is a cable of 400 Ohm, when you add parasitic C load it gets worse. When you change the cable to 100 Ohms , it gets worse.  but Prop time is 5ns/m with 1st echo at 10% of 20MHz and 2nd echo at 20% of cycle, so This IC is not ideal for typical UTP or STP cable.

Comment: Note on page 18 they agree with me that "maximum data rates in the data sheet assume that the output impedance of the external driver is less than 50 Ω"  So I would ask you to define your signal integrity specs and assumptions for impedances on source, cable and load and phase coherence and make anew question or update this one.

Comment: Regarding to initial delay, I don't care as long as the signal is stable after some time. The scenario is the following. I send a command to the delay line, the clk is delayed by 250 ps, I do some operations in my MCU and evaluate the results.  I delay the clk again, evaluate again ... until I get 360 degrees (total of 50 ns delay). So at each 250 ps I perform some analysis in the MCU. Regarding signal integrity, the clk signal from the instrument A to delay line to MCU must be good enough to be used as the MCU clk. Cable is BNC or SMA.

Comment: How many MCU cycles in 50ns? (1?) 250ps is useless

Comment: I think you don't understand my problem. It is not useless, I was introducing delay (phase) with an FPGA (step of 50 ps) but could only go to 20 ns of total delay, I need at least one clk cycle. I have two instruments, A and B. B uses the clk provided by A. B must delay (introduce phase) in the incoming clk with steps of 250 ps up to 360 degrees (one clk cycle). That is all.

Comment: Why didn't you define the problem clearly with a block diagram  Signals A and B are 20 MHz must be coherent within 0.x% of  50ns .  The source and destination IC's are with Vdd= and tolerance. Path length = 1m and coax is 50ohms.   Then describe how phase error is detected  .e.g. which edge and voltage threshold, rise time. Then detail the issues of errors , stability, signal integrity and show results.  I have had to resolve this issue many times. Normal line buildout equalization problems.

Comment: Because my question is related to the datasheet, I didn't think that exposing the whole circuit was necessary. Furthermore when the question is too long people tend to ignore it (TL;DR sort of thing).

Comment: Of course , but I tend to view this as an XY question. Asking about basic details about the differences  in distortion a pullup R makes when the approach appears to not make sense or incorrect without a basic purpose and there are transmission line mismatch effects.  So what is this for?

Comment: I created an image explaining how my "system" works. Please take a look here:https://pasteboard.co/XtFF9gUQ9Slw.png